# Vue js and htaccess

Tags: vue.js, .htaccess

I have root project with 3 folders :

- api
- admin
- frontend

on my root my .htaccess is :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/frontend/dist/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /frontend/dist/$1 [NC,L]
```

My front is live with no problems, but i can't access to my admin, so i tried :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(admin)($|/) - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/frontend/dist/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /frontend/dist/$1 [NC,L]
```

But unfortunately, it doesn't work. I have to access to https://localhost:8000/admin/xxx

If someone can help me :) thanks a lot and have a nice day

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work" exactly? What is happening? The rule you added should already do what you are asking. It prevents the second rule from being processed for any requests to `/admin` or `/admin/<anything>`.

Comment: My bad, it works because i put a index.html test in my admin folder. When i go to https://localhost:8000/admin, i see the test. I think i have to create another .htaccess in my admin folder to jump automatically in my dist folder